# fdt_addr not setup by U-Boot/first stage bootloader

Tags: raspberry-pi3, boot, u-boot, buildroot

I'm working on setting up U-Boot for our systems using raspberry pi 3B plus and cm3. (Though atm I'm working just with cm3. I'm confident the same applies to the 3B plus)
I got rid of the default bootcmd `run distro_bootcmd` and load a first stage boot script `first_boot.scr` which then loads and sources the respected `boot.scr`.

%EDIT%
In my answer I mentioned already that the failure description is wrong. I just checked the `fdt_addr` variable at the wrong time, thus leading me on the wrong path.
%EDIT%
As we already have machines out in the field I'm working on updating them. Here lies the problem. If I setup a fresh device with the new architecture everything works just fine. If I update and older system though, `fdt_addr` is not setup, thus the boot failes.
I can of course manually setup `fdt_addt`, but I want to understand what could be the reason for `fdt_addr` not being setup. As far as I could find, the first stage bootloader is responsible. So I imagine something is not beeing triggered.

Updating in our case describes simply copying the new images to the device, moving `u-boot.bin` and `first_boot.scr` to the boot partition and then changing the `config.txt` to start U-Boot not the kernel directly.
While setting up a fresh machine is pretty much the same just with formatting the device and placing the files in the exact same places.

bootcmd: `load mmc 0:1 ${scriptaddr} /first_boot.scr; source ${scriptaddr}`

```
env load  #<- %EDIT%
if test "${boot_count}" > 4; then
        echo "###Loading factory kernel bootscript###"
        setenv boot_kernel 2;
        load mmc 0:2 ${scriptaddr} images/factory/boot.scr;
        source ${scriptaddr}
elif test "${boot_count}" > 2; then
        echo "###Loading factory kernel bootscript###"
        setenv boot_kernel 1;
        load mmc 0:2 ${scriptaddr} images/previous/boot.scr;
        source ${scriptaddr}
else
        echo "###Loading current kernel bootscript###"
        setenv boot_kernel 0;
        load mmc 0:2 ${scriptaddr} images/latest/boot.scr;
        source ${scriptaddr}
fi
```

```
if test "${boot_kernel}" = 2; then
        echo "###Loading factory kernel###"
        load mmc 0:2 ${kernel_addr_r} images/factory/Image;
        load mmc 0:2 ${fdt_addr} images/factory/device_tree.dtb;
elif test "${boot_kernel}" = 1; then
        echo "###Loading previous kernel###"
        load mmc 0:2 ${kernel_addr_r} images/previous/Image;
        load mmc 0:2 ${fdt_addr} images/previous/device_tree.dtb;
else
        echo "###Loading current kernel###"
        load mmc 0:2 ${kernel_addr_r} images/latest/Image;
        load mmc 0:2 ${fdt_addr} images/latest/device_tree.dtb;
fi

setenv bootargs console=ttyAMA0,115200 printk.devkmsg=on usbcore.autosuspend=-1 fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes
env save
booti ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr}
```

Comment: Typically environment variable fdt_addr_r is used for the device tree not fdt_addr.

Comment: I once stumbled upon this comment [link](https://www.elinux.org/RPi_U-Boot#Booting_from_an_SD_card) stating `# IMPORTANT NOTE: On mainline u-boot, the correct variable to use here is ${fdt_addr} and NOT ${fdt_addr_r}`
Also if I use `fdt_addr_r` I just get `ERROR: Did not find a cmdline Flattened Device Tree
Could not find a valid device tree`. 

If I could manage to use `fdt_addr_r` though that would solve my problem potentially. 

Then on the other hand I'd still like to understand how `fdt_addr` gets set normally and why it is not set in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was a line I sadly left out in my example as I deemed it unimportant...
I work with the `boot_count` variable also in user land, for that reason I save my environment to the drive so I can interact with it via `fw_saveenv`.
Because of that I need to load the environment at the beginning of `first_boot.scr`.
But if you try to load with `env load` when there is no `uboot.env` file alot of the environment information is lost. So now I do a check for `uboot.env` and save if it is not present and load if so.

I described the problem wrong in my question though. I check the presence of `fdt_addr` before sourching `first_boot.scr` at times, thus getting lead on the wrong track.

```
if test -e mmc 0:1 uboot.env; then
        echo "Loading env"
        env load
else
        echo "Saving default environment to file"
        env save
fi

if test "${boot_count}" > 4; then
        echo "###Loading factory kernel bootscript###"
        setenv boot_kernel 2;
        load mmc 0:2 ${scriptaddr} images/factory/boot.scr;
        source ${scriptaddr}
elif test "${boot_count}" > 2; then
        echo "###Loading factory kernel bootscript###"
        setenv boot_kernel 1;
        load mmc 0:2 ${scriptaddr} images/previous/boot.scr;
        source ${scriptaddr}
else
        echo "###Loading current kernel bootscript###"
        setenv boot_kernel 0;
        load mmc 0:2 ${scriptaddr} images/latest/boot.scr;
        source ${scriptaddr}
fi
```